# Minimum required Texture Size for compliance with OpenGL-ES 2.0 on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, specifications

is there a minimum texture size a certain hardware needs to support to be compliant with the OpenGL-ES 2.0 specification ?

Something like the GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE value has to be at least 1024 or 2048 or something like that ?

The reason I would like to know this is because I work on something that uses shaders and as such has to be OpenGL-ES 2.0. Therefore I would like to make the textures as big as possible without having to consider each and every hardware texture limitation (like the old phones with only 512x512).

If there was a minimum number (or a certain value that most devices support) that would help me alot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, any GLES2 implementation must support at least 64 pixel texture in width and height.
You can query actual actual max texture size with glGetIntegerv function using GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE enum.

See official spec page 141, table 6.20.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and found it at http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.24.pdf pg. 149 table 6.17 and it really says minimum 64 pixels. This is just a laughably small number for my needs and I guess I just have to stick to minimum textures of 1024 and hope thats good enough.

Comment: Yes, that's the same spec, but older version. Latest is 2.0.25 from November 2, 2010. But the limit is the same.

Comment: Agree to `HardCoder`, this is ridiculous. Any thoughts on it? For example, on official android site there is a nice pie chart showing distribution of currently used versions of Android. Is there a similar statistics for texture size? (and other useful info)

Comment: @sargeborsch OpenGL is not android-only, so while the minimum texture size seems ridiculous for *our* needs, or for android device needs, that doesn't mean OpenGL should discard some of its device support just to suit us. =)