# AndEngine - size of BuildableTextureAtlas

Tags: java, android, andengine

So I'm wondering whether it's still true if size of my atlases should be max 1024*1024. In app I'm developing I have some backgrounds with width of 2400 px (also multi-layered background) so my biggest Buildable Atlas has a size of 4000*2500. I tested it on multiple devices (low-end and high-end) and to this moment I found only one that couldn't deal with it (an old lenovo tablet). So is it today really such an issue to have big Texture Atlases and if so, what is the best way to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation of texture size on every device. The specification says that the maximum size must be bigger than the screen. The manufacturers then decide what is the maximum they are going to support.

There are still devices that have the limit set to 1024x1024 pixels, but 2048x2048 is more common. Since the buildable texture atlas is stored as a texture, the same limit applies.

See [Android devices GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE limitation, safe texture size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931295/android-devices-gl-max-texture-size-limitation-safe-texture-size) for more details.

I recommend splitting the big atlas into smaller ones and assemble your backgrounds from pieces.